# Baking granbarksost (spruce bark cheese) (Brie) with little mould

Tags: baking, food-safety, cheese

We have this amazing cheese from Sweden just like Brie cheese but surrounded by tree bark and meant for baking.  Should I remove the little bits of green mould from the outside of the cheese before baking for 10 mins - or will the heat kill any nasties in the mold? Temperature recommended is 150 degrees C for 10 mins.

Answer (score 2):

Some mold spores can withstand high temps and the toxins produced by "bad" mold don't break down into something safe because they are heated.  Brie and brie-like cheeses are supposed to have white mold, but green is a different mold, and unless you know that particular green mold is safe to eat, I'd cut it off.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the mould is fine (ie. relatively normal) for (unpasteurized) Brie cheeses of that nature.  However, should the mould develop **fur** (white hairs) then discard the cheese.  Or at least chop away the mouldy parts and a generous excess bordering the mould also.

Comment: Where did you read this? Normal brie is very moldy. It's a puff ball of mold that gets smashed when packed to form the rind. Is the mold you are seeing different than the mold that made the brie what it is?

Comment: I asked the shop attendant who buys the cheese directly from the Dairy.  This Brie only has the white mouldy casing as the circular tube it sits in (So around the outside of the circle of cheese).  The top and bottom are basically mold free (No white layer).  This top area was starting to get mould - which prompted my question here.